# Bootstrap Accordion JQuery/Javascript error in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am currently working on a Drupal 7 with a bootstrap 3 theme and I have run into a problem where all of my Bootstrap Accordions (from the [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module) are not expanding when being clicked. I am using the Panels Module on this site and have set all of my panels using the [Panels Bootstrap Layouts](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_bootstrap_layouts) Module as well.I have noticed that in my chrome console I am receiving the following errors when any page on the site loads:[image]

Any ideas as to why this may be happening? I have installed the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) Module as well as the [jQuery plugins](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_plugin) Module and updated all of the themes to use jQuery 2.1.

Comment: It is because your `jquery.js` is not loaded properly.. Check in the console's **sources** tab for the `jquery.js` file.. If it is present then order of loading the file is not proper.. It has to be loaded before any `js` file you load..

Comment: Ok thanks for the help this actually helped me find the root of my problem. It actually ended up being some faulty modules in Drupal 7 that were likely missing parts, once I disabled them the jQuery was loaded correctly and now it works.